# Cannnot access this.context when getting Instance from Class in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call method **actionContext** in Class **BaseComponent** from my Container function but **this.context** is **undefined** (I won't use class in Container.tsx) . Please Do you Know what I am missing in my syntax Instance ? Noting that I cannot modify the BaseComponentClass.js because we don't have right .

**Container.tsx:**

```
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

  export default function Container(props) {

  let BaseInstance = new BaseComponent(props);

  useEffect(()=>{

    BaseInstance.actionContext(); // error 

  },[])

  return (
     <div>
        hello
     </div>
  );
};
```

**BaseComponentClass.js :**

```
import React, { Component, RefObject } from 'react';

export interface BaseProps {
   readOnly?: boolean;
}

export abstract class BaseComponent<P extends BaseProps, S, M extends 
ComponentInstanceParamsBase> extends Component<P, S> {

static contextType = CommonsContext;

protected componentRef: RefObject<any>;

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.componentRef = React.createRef()
}

get component() {
    return this.componentRef.current;
}

get actionContext() {
    return this.context.actionContext;//here there is no Context in this
}

get metadataContext(): M {
    return this.context.metadataContext;
}
```

}

Comment: It's totally unclear where you expect `this.context` to come from, or what you expect its value to be. Nowhere in your code do you create or even declare that property.

Comment: You should not instantiate React components with `new` yourself. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Te goal is to not use classes . I want to use  function with an instantiation of the class instead of class extends class. The only way I can see is through instatiation

Comment: You mean you originally had working code with `class Container extends BaseComponent { … }`, but want to switch to function components?

Comment: yes this is my main target

Comment: Well if you say you can't touch/modify/replace `BaseComponent`, then this is impossible.